# Redirect to html page based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box on a webpage where the user enters a location of a city. I want that to be incorporated into the url. I have a Spring controller that handles those url's but I am having trouble redirecting to that url in the first place. Here is my code

```
<span id = "form">
            <form  id = "input" target="_self" action="http://localhost:8090/location/city" method="GET" th:action="@{/location/city}">
                <label for="loc" align = right>Location:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Location" th:name= "location" id="loc">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setMode()">
            </form>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("input").action = "http://localhost:8090/location/" + document.getElementById("loc").value;
            </script>
```

I only want to add the name of the city but when the users clicks submit the url becomes "/?location=cityname" I want "/location/cityname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setMode()">
```

type="submit" will trigger basic browser standards for submitting forms. When you change it to a anchor link without href it will work. You can of course style the anchor link to look like an button. Other wise you should use event.preventDefault(); to prevent form for submitting.

You can use;

```
<a onclick='setMode()' >Submit</a>
```

Instead of;

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setMode()">
```

Comment: Could you clarify on how you would assign the input value once the user input is completed and the submit button is pressed? The setMode() method was not intended for that originally. Sorry for not telling what the method did.